# How to comment on .tsx file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, comments, tsx

I want to comment TSX code that I showed below. How can I do that?

`<Form.Group controlId="type"> <Form.Label>Type</Form.Label>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a few ways.

### Single line (Option 1)

```
<Form.Group controlId="type">
  {/* Hello World */}
  <Form.Label>Type</Form.Label>
</Form.Group>
```

### Single line (Option 2)

```
<Form.Group controlId="type">
  {
    // Hello World
  }
  <Form.Label>Type</Form.Label>
</Form.Group>
```

### Multi-line

```
<Form.Group controlId="type">
  {/* 
    Hello 
    World 
  */}
  <Form.Label>Type</Form.Label>
</Form.Group>
```

### Attribute comment

```
<Form.Group /* Hello World */ controlId="type">
  <Form.Label>Type</Form.Label>
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 20):

To add a comment in the middle of JSX, use curly brackets to pop back into plain javascript, then add your comment:

```
<Form.Group controlId="type">
  {/* Hello World */}
  <Form.Label>Type</Form.Label>
</Form.Group>
```

Typescript doesn't change this.